# Gill Sans font family rendering with @font-face

Tags: html, css, fonts, rendering

I am new in rendering fonts with @font-face. I am using Gill Sans font family in my design.
I did research to understand make it work for me but I am not able to understand how to use it. The font type I am using dont have `.eot` and `.woff` font type. I can just see gill sans font true type font in my font folder.

I would like to see if anyone can help to understand how it works and make it easy for me to use this.
I am not able to understand what is happening in the below code.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, different browsers want fonts in different formats. You can generate the other formats from your .ttf file here:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

You can then use your font in CSS using the name you defined (MyWebFont).

```
body {
    font-family: MyWebFont;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for Gill Sans though... (Adobe won't let you)... you must buy the webfont separately.